# Network packets routing

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, routing, raspberry-pi

I have implemented mesh network on 5 raspberry pi.
I will attach a camera to the 5th node which takes the pictures/video and transfer the captured data to the first node and then to the server.The network protocol is 802.11s.

I have implemented the network using following commands.

sudo iw phy phy0 interface add mesh1 type mp
sudo iw dev set channel 10
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig mesh1 10.0.0.11
sudo iw dev mesh1 mesh join biz

This is the script which automatically runs whenever the system restarts. It will create one virtual mesh interface.

All the nodes are in same channel which is 10.
All the nodes are in same mesh network which is biz(Mesh Id).
IPs are 10.0.0.11 - 10.0.0.15

In the above diagram 5 node take pictures/video and transfers the data to the available neighbour node and then it transfers to the other available neighbour node. It should choose the best path to transfer the data. Like 5-4-2-1 or 5-4-3-1.

Or if the either of the nodes are unavailable it should redirect the packets to the different node.

For example, in 5-4-2-1 path if node if node 4 is unavailable it should redirect the packets to 5-2-1 if the 2 node is available or should choose the alternative path automatically either 5-4-3-1 or 5-3-1.

So my question is ..how to archive everything from mesh 5 to server and to redirect all package to best way?

[image]

Comment: Good information. It appears you forgot to ask your question. :-)

Comment: So my question is ..how to archive everything from mesh 5 to server and to redirect all package to best way?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking either. You've already created a mesh network, so why are you asking how to create a mesh network?

Comment: No .. i want to make arhive (copy folders with pictures and videos)  from mesh 5 (videos and pictures) to server but with redirection of TCP packets :For example, in 5-4-2-1 path if node if node 4 is unavailable it should redirect the packets to 5-2-1 if the 2 node is available or should choose the alternative path automatically either 5-4-3-1 or 5-3-1.